# java open a file(pdf,xsl,etc...) from mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, desktop

I have files(pdf,doc,txt,xsl,etc..) stored in my *mongo* *db*. I want to retrieve and open them. I know to extract. Also  I found out that `Desktop.getDesktop().open(FileName);` will open the file with its respective application(Acrobat reader, office suite etc). But can anyone please tell me if only the file would be enough or we should give the full path for the file.

In the latter case, can anyone plesae tell me how I could path for the file which is being retrieved from *mongodb*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to extract the file from Mongodb if you want to open it using `Desktop.getDesktop().open(FileName);`

You can create a temp file using [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and write in it the content fetched from mongodb, with the correct file extension, and then run `Desktop.getDesktop().open()` to open it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BY "write in the content fetched" u mean write using the input stream n output stream? correct me if I am wrong. Also I assume this can be done in the case of remote servers too...

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, if you want to open a file coming from mongodb on your desktop machine, you'll have to write it locally so that your system can retrieve it. This is not specific to mongodb.